# Making read-only fields in a Vue observable?

Tags: vue.js

I'm exposing a Vue observable that reflects sign-in status:

```
// auth.js
const user = Vue.observable({
  displayName: '...',
  isSignedIn: null    // Boolean
});

...

export { user };
```

Though the name is `observable`, I think anyone importing `user` can also modify the fields. How could I prevent this?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but don't rely on client JavaScript for security, just for interface management.  Check permissions with the server any time you access data.

Comment: *Though the name is observable, I think anyone importing user can also modify the fields. How could I prevent this?* - why is this a problem? Who else is expected to import it?

Comment: @Dan This is not an issue of client side permissions. Just an interface question between my 'auth.js' and rest of my code.

Comment: @EstusFlask You're right. It's not really a problem (all code would come from me). I'm just re-learning Vue and trying to see what patterns I'd keep using. Tried ES6 getters for the above code, but it doesn't compile. It's about showing the intent, I think. And... since 'observable' has that name, I'm kind of expecting other modules wouldn't even be able to change the fields. Maybe I'll just delete the question.

Comment: No, you shouldn't worry about it. From my experience, excessive encapsulation in JS isn't worth it at all. Since isSignedIn is supposed to be set at some point, there's a way to modify it, one way or another. You can use types (TS) and mark the field as readonly if you're concerned about accidental misuse in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can freeze the object before make it reactive, like this example below.

```
const user = Vue.observable(
        Object.freeze({
          displayName: '...',
          isSignedIn: true   // Boolean
        })
      );
```

The question is why to use this, better to expose a non-reactive object. Check the Vue.observable definition [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable)